# Joomla: double domainname in menu url after cloning site

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, clone, joomla3.0

Problem: After i cloned a site to the productionserver (using akeeba and kickstart) i saw that all my menulinks had double domainnames in them. So like this:

http://www.domain.com/domain.com/contact.

The links are working, but i cant find where this is gone wrong.

I tried to turn of the seo/sef/.htaccess and it stil produced a double domainname. Cleaned cache, disabled sef. 
O and BTW, if i manualy remove the extra domainname in the url bar, the link also works...

Nothing worked for me...

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Check the .htaccess file especially for any `RewriteBase` statements and/or try temporarily copying the default htaccess.txt to .htaccess to see if this helps.

Also check if anything is set for the live_site parameter in the `configuration.php` file.